# How to connect Orange Pi 3 lts to Pixhawk?

Tags: debian, debian-bullseye

I'm trying to connect Orange Pi 3 to Pixhawk using UART TX RX pins. Which pin should i use? And which connection string should I write on dronekit library? Like `/dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: This question is better suited for the [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Someone asked a question about orange pi on Raspberry Pi community, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/how-can-i-start-processing-audio-on-orange-pi-zero-a-board-similar-to-rpi  That's the raspberry forum, it wouldn't be right to ask there

Comment: Welcome to the community. In your shoes I'd drop this question to either Pixhawk or OrangePi community - or even both. Methinks that's your best bet for answer.